# If condition formula in excel isn't working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Sheet 1]

Hello All,

I'm working on If condition formula for get yes / no result. In Column "A",I'm having some values & some value are noted as "#N/A". In next 3 column I've inserted if formula, for getting if value is present then it's "Yes" if value is "#N/A" then "No".

Below are 3 if formula didn't work for "#N/A" values". At last column "E" I've provided actual result needed.

Formulas are

Column "B" : =IF(A2<>"#N/A","Yes","No")

Column "C" : =IF(A2="#N/A","No","Yes")

Column "D" : =IF(A2<>"#N/A","Yes",IF(A2="#N/A","No","Yes"))

Please let me know if any of the formula need changes?

Comment: You're comparing the values to the string `#N/A` rather than the not available *error*. Use `ISNA()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula worked.

```
=IF(ISNA(A2),"No","Yes")
```

Comment: You can just use `ISNA(A2)` if a boolean response suffices.